# Vue Error - Can't resolve 'https' when importing package

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I'm trying to make a Vue project and use an npm package for connecting to the retroachievements.org api to fetch some data, but I'm getting an error. Here's my process from start to finish to create the project and implement the package.

- Navigate to my projects folder and use the vue cli to create the project: `vue create test`. For options, I usually chose not to include the linter, vue version 2, and put everything in package.json.
- cd into the /test folder: `cd test` and install the retroachievements npm package: `npm install --save raapijs`
- Modify App.vue to the following (apologies for code formatting, not sure why the post isn't formatting/coloring it all properly...):

  const RaApi = require('raapijs');

  export default {
  name: 'App',

  ```
    data: () => ({
        api:null,
        user: '<USER_NAME>',
        apiKey: '<API_KEY>',
    }),

    created() {
        this.api = new RaApi(this.user, this.apiKey);
    },
  ```

  }
- run `npm run serve' and get the error:

  ERROR in ./node_modules/raapijs/index.js 2:14-30

  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Projects\Web\test\node_modules\raapijs'

I'm on Windows 10, Node 16.17.0, npm 8.15.0, vue 2.6.14, vue CLI 5.0.8, raapijs 0.1.2.

The first solution below says he can run it without error but it looks like the exact same code as I'm trying. Can anyone see a difference and a reason for this error?

EDIT: I reworded this post to be more clear about my process and provide more info, like the versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the raapijs package was designed to be used in a Node environment, rather than in Vue's browser based environment, so that's the reason I was getting an error. The package itself was looking for the built in https package in Node, but since it wasn't running in Node, it wasn't finding it.

So I solved my problem by looking at the package's github repo and extractingt he actual php API endpoints that were being used and using those in my app directly, rather than using the package wrapper. Not quite as clean and tidy as I was hoping but still a decent solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. I installed raapijs with `npm install --save raapijs` command. Then in my Vue version 2 component I used your code as follow:

```js
const RaApi = require('raapijs');

export default {
  
  data: () => ({
    api: null,
    user: '<USER_NAME>',
    apiKey: '<API_KEY>',
  }),
  
   created() {
    this.api = new RaApi(this.user, this.apiKey);
  },
};
```

Comment: But thats the exact same code I posted, just using require instead of import, which Ive already tried. Just to be thorough, I copy/pasted your solution code and I still get the error. I dont see the difference in what you're doing vs what I'm doing....

Comment: Did you run ```npm install --save raapijs``` in your terminal?

Comment: Yes, still getting that error

Comment: I am using node ```v14.17.1``` on ```windows 10``` and Vue version ```2.6.11```. It works without error for me.

Comment: Im on Node v14.15.5 on windows 10 and vue 2.6.14. I wonder if updating Node would help? We;re very close on version but maybe something small was changed? Latest version on the node.js website is 16.17.0

Comment: I updated node to v16.17.0, but still getting the same error. What method do you use to setup your vue project? I navigate to my projects folder then run `vue create test`. Then `cd test` to go into the /test folder, then I ran `npm install --save raapijs`. Lastly I copy/pasted your code verbatim (and plugged in my username and api key details) but whenever I run `npm run serve' I get the same error. Sorry thats lengthy but I wanted to give full transparency on my process.

Comment: I also use vue-cli version ```4.5.0```, maybe that makes the difference.